# How to pass data from an activity to a fragment in TabHost?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have a page divided like this: there is the "Main" layout which holds a fragment

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.x.x.FirstFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/first_fragment" />
```

Inside that fragment in an external layout I've created a TabHost like this:

```
<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.x.x.First"
                tools:layout="@layout/first" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/second"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.x.x.Second"
                tools:layout="@layout/second" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The problem is that I need to run a method inside the "First" class when a button inside the "Main" class has been clicked.

I've been struggling with this problem since yesterday, is there any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: By first class you mean Fragment inside MainAtivity or what?

Comment: The "First" class is inside first_fragment layout which correspond to a "FirstFragment" class

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method of First.class from the Main.class by simply using this code.
Inside your Main.class

```
new First.method();
```

Comment: I've done that, but now it tells me:

    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment First{19231ca} not attached to Activity

I belive it has something to do with the onAttach() function, but where do I implement it? I need the method called to be run when the user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a public method inside First fragment and invoke when push button on MainACtivity. Be aware of that fragment is currently shown if you want to update some fragment's UI element.

Take a look at [Fragments developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).

> Likewise, your activity can call methods in the fragment by acquiring a reference to the Fragment from FragmentManager, using findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag().

Answer (score 0):

From your Activity, get the Fragment and call the method.

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.first);
if(fragment != null){    
  ((First)fragment).yourMethod();
}
```